# How to fade a pushbutton until tables are filled in GUI MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have 3 tables which are filled by 3 pushbuttons. I want to have some computation on them by pressing `compute.pushbutton` But first I want user to insert all of the data into the tables and then  show him/her compute pushbutton. I turn the compute pushbutton visibility off and then write these code

1. **pushbutton 1** function

   ```
    function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

    global mat_index;
    [Iname,Ipath]= uigetfile('*.xlsx','Select Index Excel File');
    mat_index = xlsread(strcat(Ipath,Iname));
    table_as_cell1 = num2cell(mat_index);
    set(handles.uitable1, 'Data', table_as_cell1);
   ```
2. **pushbutton 2** function

   ```
    function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

    global mat_length;
    [lng_name,lng_path]= uigetfile('*.xlsx','Select Length Excel File');
    mat_length = xlsread(strcat(lng_path,lng_name));
    table_as_cell2 = num2cell(mat_length);
    set(handles.uitable2, 'Data', table_as_cell2);
   ```
3. **pushbutton 3** function

   ```
    function pushbutton3_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

    global mat_coordinate;
    [cord__name,cord_path]=uigetfile('*.xlsx','Select coordinate Excel 
     File');
    mat_coordinate = xlsread(strcat(cord_path,cord__name));
    table_as_cell3 = num2cell(mat_coordinate);
    set(handles.uitable3, 'Data', table_as_cell3);
   ```

And

4. **compute** pushbutton

   ```
   function pushbutton4_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

     if(isstored(mat_length) && isstored(mat_index) && 
             isstored(mat_coordinate))
   {
       set(handles.pushbutton4,'visible','on');
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You could trace which buttons have been pressed. Initialize a variable as `handles.ButtonsPressed = [false , false , false]`. Then add this function and call it within your callbacks:

```
function updateButtons(n , handles)
    % n is the latest button pressed
    handles.ButtonsPressed(n) = true;
    if all(handles.ButtonsPressed)
        set(handles.pushbutton4,'visible','on');
    end
```

So in your `pushbutton1` you should add `updateButtons(1 , handles)`.

---

You can generalize it:
Initialize:

```
 handles.Buttons2Validate = [handles.pushbutton1 , ...
                             handles.pushbutton2 , handles.pushbutton3];
 handles.ButtonsPressed(1 : numel(handles.Buttons2Validate)) = false;
```

And modify the checking function:

```
function updateButtons(hObject , handles)
    % hObject is the handle of the button pressed
    position = handles.Buttons2Validate == hObject;
    handles.ButtonsPressed(position) = true;
    if all(handles.ButtonsPressed)
        set(handles.pushbutton4,'visible','on');
    end
```

Comment: So you mean **MATLAB** is not as smart as I Think ?

Comment: What do you mean? You cannot put the visibility on/off code within pushbutton4 if it is not visible; the user will not be able to click it and it will never become visible!

Comment: I got it. Where should I declare `handles.ButtonsPressed`? Should I declare it as global ?

Comment: You can declare `ButtonsPressed` (without handles) as global, but it is better practice to use handles. More info on how to [Store or retrieve UI data](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html)